# Target only single product pages with CSS in WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-quantity

With CSS I am basically hidding quatity fields in WooCommerce using `display:none`. But it removes quantity fields on Cart and Wishlist pages as well.

How can I only target single product pages?

I can do it by page ID as well but I have 100's of products and it's just not a practical way to do it.

Comment: Just using the body class `single-product` in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To target Woocommerce Single product page just use the `<body>` class `single-product`.

Like for example to hide quantity fields (only on single product pages):

```css
.single-product .quantity {
    display:none;
}
```